# Multiple unique random samples?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, sampling

I'm trying to produce $n$ random samples from a list, but not *all* samples, and I'd like the samples to not repeat in the same execution of the command. If I'm not mistaken, something like `Permutations[]` for not all permutations, or `RandomPermutation` for a list, or a hypothetical `MultipleRandomSample[]`. Is there something I'm misinterpreting or a way to generate such collections of random samples?

Edit:
What I'm calling random samples are actually subsets, since they are fixed size and order doesn't matter. Now, I only need to take $n$ *random* subsets from a set.

`RandomSample` repeats "subsets":

```
Table[RandomSample[{2, 3, 5, 8}, 3], 10]
{{3, 2, 5}, {5, 8, 2}, {8, 3, 2}, {8, 5, 2}, {2, 3, 5}, {8, 2, 3}, {2,
   3, 8}, {2, 5, 3}, {8, 3, 5}, {2, 8, 5}}
```

`Subsets` is adequate, but it gives *all* subsets, and I wish to find $n$ *random* subsets:

```
Subsets[{2, 3, 5, 8}, {3}]
{{2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 5, 8}}
```

A simulated result would be:

```
Table[Op[{2, 3, 5, 8}, {3}],3]
{{{2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 5, 8}},
{{2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 8}, {3, 5, 8}},
{{2, 3, 8}, {2, 5, 8}, {2, 5, 8}},
{{2, 3, 8}, {2, 5, 8}, {2, 5, 8}}(*repetitions are ok*)}
```

Is there a way to produce such collections of subsets without obtaining *all* subsets, randomizing, and taking $n$?

Comment: Why doesn't `Table[RandomSample[list, k], {n}]` suit your needs?

Comment: I don't know if ```RandomSample[]``` could repeat.

Comment: Under the "Details" section of the docs: "`RandomSample` ... never samples ... more than once."

Comment: I take that to mean it wouldn't repeat elements in a sample, not that it wouldn't select the same sample again, no?

Comment: Then perhaps something like `Partition[RandomSample[list], k]` to generate all non-overlapping `k`-samples, and take the first few as needed?

Comment: Usually when one insists on random samples there is some quantity of interest to be estimated.  What might that be?  Also, if you need restricted random samples, it's usually for some reason of efficiency/balance.  Maybe if you explained why you think you need restricted random samples, you'd get more direct answers.

Comment: @JimB: Statistics for sample statistics such as mean and variance taken from sample counts less than all possible samples of a specified size; where it might be of interest to compare to the same statistics among all samples.

Comment: We might have learned Statistics in different ways.  Statistics aren't compared but parameters and parameter estimators are.  Again, there are many great reasons for using restricted randomization protocols.  However, I'm still not seeing anything that would warrant something other than simple random samples.  (Latin squares is an example of a restricted randomization as are partially balanced incomplete block designs.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the 3-arg syntax for Subsets. Here is a function that does this:

```
MultipleRandomSubsets[list_, length_, count_] := Module[{total},
    total = Binomial[Length @ list, length];
    Join @@ Map[Subsets[list, {length}, {#}]&] @ RandomSample[1 ;; total, count] /; count <= total
]
```

Small example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
MultipleRandomSubsets[{2,3,5,8}, 3, 3]
```

> {{3, 5, 8}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 3, 5}}

An example that couldn't be done by enumerating all samples:

```
SeedRandom[1]
MultipleRandomSubsets[Range[100], 10, 10]
```

> {{16, 23, 32, 33, 45, 49, 70, 72, 85, 92}, {17, 18, 31, 41, 43, 64, 
>     80, 87, 88, 97}, {1, 13, 18, 37, 40, 43, 46, 48, 61, 88}, {5, 19, 
>     22, 40, 43, 53, 58, 68, 73, 88}, {19, 28, 60, 76, 83, 85, 95, 96, 
>     98, 99}, {9, 30, 32, 46, 53, 66, 77, 86, 89, 90}, {1, 9, 19, 20, 21,
>      28, 51, 76, 80, 96}, {9, 16, 22, 61, 67, 69, 79, 82, 98, 99}, {8, 
>     34, 40, 43, 80, 82, 84, 87, 96, 98}, {13, 34, 38, 44, 47, 48, 49, 
>     67, 74, 80}}

Comment: It's good to explicitly point out two lesser-known features: 1. **`RandomSample` can take a `Span` object.** This is critical, as we couldn't possibly generate the entire (huge) integer range to sample from. 2. **`Subsets` can directly generate the `n`th subset**.  These two features make it possible to defeat combinatorial explosion.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a request for clarification that can't be made in a comment.

I'm confused by your question because it seems to me to be open to several interpretations. Here are three that immediately occur to me.

Suppose that `sample` is a function, taking no argument, that will return a random sample meeting your requirements, and suppose that we use it to generate a set of samples. Note: it may be the `sample` can not be written — we might need to generate the whole sample set at once and not sample-by-sample — but we will assume it exists for the sake of discourse.

Sample generation

```
sampleSet = With[{n = 5}, Do[sample[], n]];
```

Now, which of the following, increasingly stringent requirements does `sampleSet` have to meet?

```
require[1] = Flatten[Intersection /@ sampleSet] == {}

require[2] = Intersection @@ sampleSet == {}

require[3] = Module[{smpl = Flatten[sampleSet]}, Sort[smpl] == Union[smpl]]
```

Or is it none of the above? If the latter, please state your requirements in Mathematica code.